# Adding title to cms footer block

Tags: magento, footer, magento2

I added a second footer block with links by adding the following code to my default.xml in my theme:
(app/design/frontend///Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml)

```
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links_custom">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="footer_links_custom">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="2custom-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Links</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">page-url</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

What is the easiest way to add a title to the my footer_links_custom block, is there any way to do this in a simple manner? I've tried setting an argument "title" but that didn't work obviously. Is there any way we can know all the attributes there are for a certain block? (css_class, label, path, ...)
Is there no .phtml file for the footer links block?

Magento 2 leaves me behind with a lot of questions...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might have better luck getting this answered on the [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try reposting this over there.

Answer (score 0):

In /magento/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Theme/  You can set up the structure needed for this. and documentation to help can be found at:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html

In Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml you will find your block declarations, such as what you listed above already.

In Magento_Theme/Block/Html/Footer.php you can set up your controller with your Mage interface, such as...

```
class Footer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{

    protected $_copyright;
....
public function getCopyright()
    {
        if (!$this->_copyright) {
            $this->_copyright = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'design/footer/copyright',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
        }
        return $this->_copyright;
    }
...
```

Magento_Theme/templates/html is where you can put your .phtml that your used to working with in Magento 1.  Its not the exact same code obviously, but the idea is still the same here.  for example, here is a footer that isn't code but stored in a db:

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$manager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store = $manager->getStore(null)->getName();

$connection = $om->create('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$conn = $connection->getConnection();
$select = $conn->select()
  ->from(
      ['o' => 'xyz_sitedata_items'],
      ['footer']
  )
  ->where('o.storename=?', $store);
$data = $conn->fetchAll($select);

echo $data[0]['footer'];
```

for the record, using the object manager like this isn't recommended.

for a specific answer to the question posed, i would look to adding code to your footer.php.  you can add data in with the construct, as well as reading all the data for the associated block there.